# How to debug Qt dll issues with cross compiled builds?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, cross-compiling

After cross-compiling Qt 5 applications (host: Fedora 19/64 bit, target: Windows 32 bit) I execute following steps for deploying the executable:

```
$ DEST=/windows/testdir
$ cp /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/*.dll $DEST
$ mkdir $DEST/platforms
$ cp /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/qt5/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll\
     $DEST/platforms
$ cp release/main.exe $DEST # the cross-compiled Qt5 binary
```

I test it on Windows like this:

```
say /windows is mounted on f:
start command prompt window
f:
cd testdir
main
```

And there I get:

> Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are:

[image: qt1]

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

[image: qt2]

I don't really believe the first message because:

a) the above steps worked in the past (executed on the same Fedora 19 system)

b) the platforms directory is there as [documented in the qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html).

What changed is that now the application includes some PNGs/JPGs in dialogs (read via Qt's resource file system, as QIcons).

Thus, I've also copied some plugins:

```
$ cp -r /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/qt5/plugins $DEST
```

Which didn't help to resolve the above issue.

### Conclusion

Is there a way to debug dynamic runtime linker issues like these?

Can I instruct it such that I somehow get output on which dll's the app/linker tries to load and where is does its lookups? (and why they fail ...)

For example something like this would be great:

```
ldd: main.exe -> load of foo.dll in work-dir failed (no such file)
ldd: main.exe -> load of bar.dll in work-dir/platforms failed (wrong file format)
ldd: main.exe -> load of baz.dll in work-dir successful
...
```

### Compile steps

I used following steps for cross-compiling on Fedora 19:

```
$ mingw32-qmake-qt5 main.pro -o win32.mf
$ mingw32-make -f win32.mf
$ # -> binary is created in release/main.exe
```

### Wine

I've looked at wine for testing purposes. It is helpful because it displays an error message when it can't find a DLL, e.g.:

```
$ wine $DEST/main.exe
err:module:import_dll Library libEGL.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\usr\\i686-w64-mingw32\\sys-root\\mingw\\lib\\qt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindows.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library libjpeg-62.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\usr\\i686-w64-mingw32\\sys-root\\mingw\\lib\\qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qjpeg.dll") not found
```

Interestingly, it directly finds the platforms library and needed plugin under `Z:\\usr\\i686-w64-mingw32\\sys-root\\mingw\\lib\\qt5\\`.

But when all needed DLLs from `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/*.dll` are copied to $DEST, wine runs the same `main.exe` just fine - where on native windows (7) I get the above error boxes.

Comment: Check the platform plugin DLL with dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/ . procmon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx should show the LoadLibrary calls and where the DLLs are searched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for checking dependencies of a single DLL, [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) for quickly checking startup on the compile-host and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which directories/files are accessed during runtime of the process.

It also makes sense to debug-output the library path from the Qt application, e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)                                         
{
  qDebug() << "Library paths: " << QApplication::libraryPaths();
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  ...
```

With that I get following output on native windows:

```
Library paths:  ()
```

(To enable qDebug() statements - even with release binaries - you have to add `CONFIG += console` to your qmake project file.)

Looking at the Process Monitor output it seems that the binary does not try to open any plugins (platforms or other) in its current working directory (CWD) nor in its base directory.

When I extend the library path the binary finds all needed plugins in its CWD:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication::addLibraryPath(QDir::currentPath());
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  ...
```

I don't know if this qualifies as a work-around - perhaps one is supposed to do something like this. But the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html#creating-the-application-package) seems to suggest opposite:

> To deploy the application, we must make sure that we copy the relevant Qt DLL (corresponding to the Qt modules used in the application) and the windows platform plugin as well as the executable to the same directory in the release subdirectory.

The complete deploy procedure is now:

```bash
$ cp /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/*.dll $DEST
# copying platforms, imageformats etc. plugin directories:
$ cp /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/qt5/plugins/* $DEST -r
$ cp release/main.exe $DEST
```

(Depending on what packages are installed on your compile-host you probably don't need to copy all DLLs - with wine it is easy to start a fixpoint iteration for all needed non-plugin dlls.)

Missing non-platform plugins don't necessarily abort the programs startup - e.g. without a jpeg plugin some icons are just not displayed.